# Enabling StormCrawler to crawl a single domain with more than one spout

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am doing a proof of concept with StormCrawler and Elasticsearch for crawling just a single domain, with a few hosts - one with many many pages. Is there a way to tell stormcrawler to not group all of the urls for a host or domain in a single spout?

I followed the Youtube tutorials in setting it up, and have the spout set to 10 parallelisms, but as far as I can tell via the storm UI it is using only 1.  How do I make it spread the urls for a single domain or even a single host over all of the spouts?

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to partition the URLs per host, your config should have *partition.url.mode: "byHost"* which is the default value. This will put URLs belonging to different hosts into different shards and more spout instances will be used.

URLs from the same host are put in the same shards to enforce politeness. If you want to fetch from a host in parallel, you can simply set *fetcher.threads.per.queue* to a whichever value you want. This is acceptable if the website is your own but clearly impolite if it belongs to someone else. This will work fine even if you keep sharding per host.

Of course, you can disable routing altogether by setting *es.status.routing* to false. The URLs will be sharded by ES regardless of hostname and all the shards and spouts will be used. This implication, however, is that there is no strict control on politeness.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Since we are indexing our own internal servers, the above would all be ok, as I am also coordinating with our internal network people on hardware and network connectivity. I also noticed we could also speed up the fetch time by reducing the elasticsearch index 'refresh' time down from 5 seconds to 250ms.  With the possibility to reduce the 'politeness' of the crawl on our few servers to increase crawl speed, I am looking for a balance...since the crawl is internal, what are the repercussions of the index refresh time in elasticsearch?

Comment: reducing the ES refresh time would not affect the fetch time itself but would mean that the spout are able to get updated results quicker. it can affect the indexing performance though. As you pointed out, it is a matter of balance. You should be able to find what works for you by experimenting with different values.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!